# MYSQL query to display max values of column grouped by inner join column

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have two tables

PILOTS

| pilot_id | first_name | last_name | status | hub |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fname1 | lname1 | 1 | YBBN |
| 2 | fname2 | lname2 | 0 | YSSY |
| 3 | fname3 | lname3 | 1 | YMML |
| 4 | fname4 | lname4 | 1 | YBBN |
| 5 | fname5 | lname5 | 1 | EGLL |
| 6 | fname6 | lname6 | 1 | EGLL |
| 7 | fname7 | lname7 | 1 | EGLL |
| 8 | fname8 | lname8 | 1 | YPAD |

PIREPS

| pirep_id | pilot_id | date | landing_rate | accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-04-01 | -113 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-04-02 | -110 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-04-03 | -200 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-04-04 | -20 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2021-04-05 | -120 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 2021-04-06 | -130 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | 2021-04-07 | -132 | 1 |
| 8 | 4 | 2021-04-08 | -91 | 1 |
| 9 | 5 | 2021-04-09 | -64 | 1 |
| 10 | 6 | 2021-04-10 | -47 | 0 |
| 11 | 6 | 2021-04-11 | -112 | 1 |
| 12 | 7 | 2021-04-12 | -113 | 1 |
| 13 | 7 | 2021-04-13 | -201 | 1 |
| 14 | 1 | 2021-04-14 | -300 | 0 |
| 15 | 1 | 2021-04-15 | -301 | 1 |

EXPECTED REUSULT

| pilot_id | first_name | last_name | hub | landing_rate | date | pirep_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | fname2 | lname2 | YSSY | -20 | 2021-04-04 | 4 |
| 5 | fname5 | lname5 | EGLL | -64 | 2021-04-09 | 9 |
| 4 | fname4 | lname4 | YBBN | -91 | 2021-04-08 | 8 |
| 3 | fname3 | lname3 | YMML | -130 | 2021-04-06 | 6 |
| 8 | fname8 | lname8 | YPAD | -301 | 2021-04-15 | 15 |

The below code gives me the expected output if I only group by pilot ID and displays the best landing rate with the associated pilot and the date they completed the flight

```
SELECT pi.first_name,pi.last_name,p.pirep_id,p.pilot_id,p.date,p.landing_rate
FROM qvi_pireps p
LEFT JOIN qvi_pilots pi on p.pilot_id=pi.pilot_id
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT pilot_id as pil,date as da,MAX(landing_rate) AS max_landing_rate
    FROM qvi_pireps
    where landing_rate<0 GROUP BY pilot_id) grouppedp 
ON p.pilot_id = grouppedp.pil 
AND p.landing_rate = grouppedp.max_landing_rate  
where pi.status=1 and
accepted=1
group by p.pilot_id ORDER BY `grouppedp`.`max_landing_rate`  DESC,p.date asc limit 20
```

ABOVE QUERY OUTPUT

| first_name | last_name | pirep_id | pilot_id | date | landing_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fname2 | lname2 | 4 | 2 | 2021-04-04 | -20 |
| fname5 | lname5 | 9 | 5 | 2021-04-09 | -64 |
| fname4 | lname4 | 8 | 4 | 2021-04-08 | -91 |
| fname1 | lname1 | 2 | 1 | 2021-04-02 | -110 |
| fname6 | lname6 | 11 | 6 | 2021-04-11 | -112 |
| fname7 | lname7 | 12 | 7 | 2021-04-12 | -113 |
| fname3 | lname3 | 6 | 3 | 2021-04-06 | -130 |
| fname8 | lname8 | 15 | 8 | 2021-04-15 | -301 |

when I change `group by p.pilot_id` to `group by pi.hub` I receive the unique hubs however the pilot,landing_rate and date do not match what should be the best

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is getting the MAX(landing_rate) of each pilot where pilot.status=1 & flight.accepted=1 then group by pilot.hub to display the best hub with the highest landing rate with the pilot and date they achieved that landing rate

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your query is missing the `select` part of it. Also please provide some sample data (not as image) and from the sample data what is the expected result. Here is a good example of how a SQL question should be: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I have actioned these :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT pilot_id, date, MAX(landing_rate)
FROM qvi_pireps
GROUP BY pilot_id
```

is invalid SQL. You group by pilot and select a date. Which date? There are many dates per pilot in that table. You'd have to apply some aggregation function on `date` to get this valid. MySQL should raise an exception here (and I am sure it would, did you change from cheating mode to `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`. This should be set by default and as this doesn't seem to be the case, I surmise you are working with a old version of MySQL.

Apart from this and the inappropriate outer join and the missing `accepted` check in your subquery (which may be the main reason you are seeing incorrect dates), your query looks rather fine. Only that in your main query you group again by pilot, which makes no sense at all. Maybe you left that in by mistake when rewriting your query at some point. Here is your query corrected:

```
SELECT pil.first_name, pil.last_name, pir.pirep_id, pil.pilot_id, pir.date, pir.landing_rate
FROM qvi_pilots pil
JOIN qvi_pireps pir ON pir.pilot_id = pil.pilot_id AND pir.accepted = 1
JOIN
(
  SELECT pilot_id, MAX(landing_rate) AS max_landing_rate
  FROM qvi_pireps
  WHERE accepted = 1
  GROUP BY pilot_id
) grouppedp ON grouppedp.pilot_id = pir.pilot_id AND grouppedp.max_landing_rate = pir.landing_rate
WHERE pil.status = 1
ORDER BY pir.landing_rate DESC, pir.date ASC
LIMIT 20;
```

For readability, though I prefer an `IN` clause over a join:

```
SELECT pil.first_name, pil.last_name, pir.pirep_id, pil.pilot_id, pir.date, pir.landing_rate
FROM qvi_pilots pil
JOIN qvi_pireps pir ON pir.pilot_id = pil.pilot_id
                    AND pir.accepted = 1
                    AND (pir.pilot_id, pir.landing_rate) IN
                    (
                      SELECT pilot_id, MAX(landing_rate)
                      FROM qvi_pireps
                      WHERE accepted = 1
                      GROUP BY pilot_id
                    )
WHERE pil.status = 1
ORDER BY pir.landing_rate DESC, pir.date ASC
LIMIT 20;
```

(The same can be achieved with `NOT EXISTS (<a greater landing rate for the pilot>)` by the way.)

In current MySQL versions we would rather use a window function in order to access the qvi_pireps table only once:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, pirep_id, pilot_id, date, landing_rate
FROM
(
  SELECT
    pil.first_name, pil.last_name, pir.pirep_id, pil.pilot_id, pir.date, pir.landing_rate,
    MAX(pir.landing_rate) OVER (PARTITION BY pil.pilot_id) AS max_landing_rate
  FROM qvi_pilots pil
  JOIN qvi_pireps pir ON pir.pilot_id = pil.pilot_id AND pir.accepted = 1
  WHERE pil.status = 1
) with_max_landing_rate
WHERE landing_rate = max_landing_rate
ORDER BY landing_rate DESC, date ASC
LIMIT 20;
```

**UPDATE:** Same query for old MySQL versions, but for best rate per hub instead of best rate per pilot.

After all, this simply means we must look for the `MAX(landing_rate)` per hub instead of per pilot:

```
SELECT pil.first_name, pil.last_name, pir.pirep_id, pil.pilot_id, pir.date, pir.landing_rate
FROM qvi_pilots pil
JOIN qvi_pireps pir ON pir.pilot_id = pil.pilot_id
                    AND pir.accepted = 1
                    AND (pil.hub, pir.landing_rate) IN
                    (
                      SELECT pl.hub, MAX(pr.landing_rate)
                      FROM qvi_pireps pr
                      JOIN qvi_pilots pl USING (pilot_id) 
                      WHERE pr.accepted = 1 AND pl.status = 1
                      GROUP BY pl.hub
                    )
WHERE pil.status = 1
ORDER BY pir.landing_rate DESC, pir.date ASC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, i've changed the query to use the IN statement as suggested. I was getting the pilots table which was not what I wanted so flipped the from statement to be pireps instead at the start. 

Now that I'm getting the expected output for pilots with status 1, i need to group all pilots by their HUB and get the best pilot(determined by landing rate) for each hub with the corresponding pirep that matches

Comment: The order of tables in the `FROM` clause should have no effect on the queries. As to hubs: same, same. Instead of looking for `max(landing_rate)` per pilot, you look for it per hub. For this to happen you must join status-one pilots in your subquery. It's easier in the MySQL 8 query, where you'd only change the partition clause from pilot to hub.

Comment: ... unless you want the pilots with the maximum rates and from that result get the maximum rows per hub. That would require to put the query in a subquery and build up on that. Your description sounds like you want this, but it may well be that you just want the best row per hub, which is easier.

Comment: correct just best row per hub (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvwjR.png for context)

Comment: Well, as mentioned, join status-one pilots in your subquery, group by hub instead of pilot and that's about it. Good luck with that.

Comment: are you able to provide a snippet of code, I'm not following when you say join status-one pilots

Comment: Join the pilots table. Make sure not to forget status = 1.

Comment: Is there a reason by the way that you are working with an old MySQL version? MySQL 8 has great features not available in those old versions.

Comment: tried to add join but get "unknown column pir.pilot_id" https://i.stack.imgur.com/X80oT.png. Something to look into I think, I'm working with laravel but would make breaking changes to upgrade. Something I plan on doing overtime however no need for it as of yet

Comment: That is because you are not supposed to look for pilots, but for hubs. You correctly group by hub, but instead of selecting the hub you are still trying to select a pilot, which is wrong. I've updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: Your solution was great! If I wanted to get the average landing rate (not concerned about pilot) or the sum of how many pireps there were would this be as simple as changing max(landing_rate) to AVG(landing_rate)?

Comment: No, I don't think so. So far you are showing the pireps with the maximum rate per hub. What else it is exactly that you want? To show the pireps closest to the average rate per hub?  That doesn't sound easy. Think about what you really want and then build your query step by step. Remember that your description "Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is getting the MAX(landing_rate) of each pilot where pilot.status=1 & flight.accepted=1 then group by pilot.hub" was wrong. You didn't want the maximum rate per pilot. So, be exact in your description in order to get to a correctly working query.